# Defining a Union of a Set of Sets formula.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a formula for all $n \in \mathbb N$, Let  $B_{n} = \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \mid 3n + 2 \leq x \leq 3n + 4 \}$. Now I need to define: $\bigcup \limits_{n = 1} B_{n}$, which means I have to prove : $\bigcup \limits_{n = 1} B_{n} = \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \mid 3n + 2 \leq x \leq 3n + 4 \}$.

I have to show that :

1. $\bigcup \limits_{n = 1} B_{n} \subseteq \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \mid 3n + 2 \leq x \leq 3n + 4 \}$
2. $\{ x \in \mathbb{N} \mid 3n + 2 \leq x \leq 3n + 4 \} \subseteq \bigcup \limits_{n = 1} B_{n}$

I have no idea how to approach that. Could anyone help please?

Comment: Yeah , I tried copy/pasting and this is how it turned out :/

Comment: @PainKiller I fixed the formatting of your question.  Please review it to make sure the changes are correct.

Comment: It's correct, thanks a lot =)

Comment: The 'set' $\{ x \in \mathbb{N} \mid 3n + 2 \leq x \leq 3n + 4 \}$ isn't a set at all because $n$ isn't quantified. You probably want $\{ x \in \mathbb{N} \colon \exists n\in \mathbb N( 3n + 2 \leq x \leq 3n + 4) \}$.

Comment: That's what it says in my book, it does however say for all n∈N, which I will edit into the first post.Thanks for noticing that :)

Comment: In the definition of $B_n$, $n$ is acting as a constant and so it's fine. but $\{ x \in \mathbb{N} \colon 3n + 2 \leq x \leq 3n + 4 \}$ makes no sense. Think about it, is $5$ in this set? You can't test it because you know nothing about $n$.

Comment: I think I was probably confusing in my first post, sorry for that, I'll give you an example of what I meant, let's take B1 as an example which means B1 = {3*1 + 2 = 5,6,3*1 + 4 = 7},meaning the set B1 = {5,6,7}.

Comment: Also you say you need to define $\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(B_n\right)$. If you want to define it, you don't need to prove anything. You just need to define it and perhaps explain (this can't be proved really) why your definition is a desirable one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B_1 = \{x \in \mathbb{N} :5 \le x \le 7 \} = \{5,6,7\}$.

$B_2 = \{ x \in \mathbb{N}: 8 \le x \le 10 \} = \{8,9,10\}$.

$B_3 = \{ x \in \mathbb{N}: 11 \le x \le 13 \} = \{11, 12,13\}$. etc.

So $\cup_n B_n = \{x \in \mathbb{N} : x \ge 5 \} = \{5,6,7,\ldots\}$.

You don't have to *define* $\cup_n B_n$ (it is defined when all $B_n$ are).
You need to determine what set it is.

Comment: Thanks man, i was thinking into it too much, thanks a lot =)